# Receiving Error While passing Dynamic Values From CSV in JMETER

Tags: csv, jmeter

Please check the below steps I followed in my test.

1. First, created a CSV file with the username and password. I have done this in a text editor, and saved as .CSV file.
   My CSV Looks Like:

   `username           password
   user 1                pwd 1
   user 2                pwd 2`
2. And I placed in the Specific path and I have mentioned in the same path in CSV Data Set Configuration steps.

   `File Name          : mentioned full path of the file.
   Variable names     : username,password
   Delimiter          : ,`
3. Next I Have defined the below changes in HTTP Request

   `username with ${username} 
   password with ${password}`
4. After running the test, the passed user logins are not taking from the script and the test got failed.

please guide me if some where am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how your input file and Jmeter item should look like:

[image: CSV config]

Comment: Hi konstantin Dobroliubov, I have used username,password in my CSV file. Please guide me whether I have to do any more configuration in JMeter?

Comment: Read again what CSV file is. It can contain only one type of delimiters. So, if you use comma as a delimiter, ALL values must follow in one string and must be delimited by comma, like: username1,password1,username2,password2,etc. But your values (pairs of values) are delimited by tabulation symbol. So, use \t in this case as was mentioned by Dmitry. But don't use both - tab and comma. It's not a CSV file.

Comment: Hi, I used \t in delimiter and I am getting the below error                        Response code: 500
Response message: Internal Server Error                                                                                                                                                Also I tried with comma, the test got successful and I could not find the user name & password in the results (Which I have passed through CSV file).

Answer (score 0):

1. If your CSV file is actually separated by [tabulation symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key) you need to change the delimiter to `\t`
2. I would suggest removing leading "username" and "password" from your CSV file, JMeter won't recognise header so you'll have at least one failed request.

Other bits look good.

You may also want to check out Using [CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) guide and [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) function.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, Thanks For your reply. I will try as per your suggestion and I will let you know for further queries.

Comment: The Test Got successful but I couldn't find the user name and password from the test results(View Result Tree). I have checked each and every step. Please guide me whether JMETER not taken for the username & password from CSV?

Comment: I am looking for your support.

Comment: I was done this manually , here we need to write any script for this testing?